# How to change height between logo and slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I want use this script to display some product. The script is locate at: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemSlider/

When you resize a web browser from maximum size to smaller then height between logo and shoes is too big for me. How can I change it ?

style.css

```
@import url('demo.css');

.mi-slider {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 490px;
}

.mi-slider ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.no-js .mi-slider ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-current {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(600%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(600%);
    transform: translateX(600%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.no-js .mi-slider ul li {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.mi-slider ul li a,
.mi-slider ul li img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mi-slider ul li a {
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mi-slider ul li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

.mi-slider ul li h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 10px 0;
}

.mi-slider ul li:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
} 

.mi-slider nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 5px solid #333;
}

.no-js nav {
    display: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 40px 30px 30px 34px;
    position: relative;
    color: #888;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.mi-slider nav a:hover,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected {
    color: #000;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    border: solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-width: 27px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -27px;
}

/* Move classes and animations */

.mi-slider ul:first-child li,
.no-js .mi-slider ul li {
    -webkit-animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: scaleUp 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

@-moz-keyframes scaleUp {
    0% { -moz-transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
    0% { transform: translateX(0) scale(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0) scale(1); }
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:first-child {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 90ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 90ms;
    animation-delay: 90ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 180ms;
    animation-delay: 180ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 270ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 270ms;
    animation-delay: 270ms;
}

.mi-slider ul:first-child li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 360ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 360ms;
    animation-delay: 360ms;
}

/* moveFromRight */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveFromLeft */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveFromLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveToRight */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li {
    -webkit-animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveToRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* moveToLeft */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li {
    -webkit-animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
    animation: moveToLeft 350ms ease-in-out both;
}

/* Animation Delays */

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0ms;
    animation-delay: 0ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 90ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 90ms;
    animation-delay: 90ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(3),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:nth-child(2),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 180ms;
    animation-delay: 180ms;
}

.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToLeft li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li:nth-child(4),
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveToRight li:first-child,
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromLeft li:first-child  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 270ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 270ms;
    animation-delay: 270ms;
}

/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromRight {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(600%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromLeft {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToRight {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToLeft {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveFromRight {
    0% { -moz-transform: translateX(600%); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveFromLeft {
    0% { -moz-transform: translateX(-600%); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveToRight {
    0% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveToLeft {
    0% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

@keyframes moveFromRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(600%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes moveFromLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(-600%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes moveToRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(600%); }
}

@keyframes moveToLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-600%); }
}

.mi-slider {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 910px){
    .mi-slider nav {
        max-width: 90%;
    }
    .mi-slider nav a {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 40px 10px 30px 14px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    .mi-slider {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .mi-slider nav {
        top: 220px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 490px){ 
    .mi-slider {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
    }

    .mi-slider ul {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
        bottom: auto;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .mi-slider ul li {
        -webkit-animation: none !important;
        -moz-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
        padding: 10px 3px;
        min-width: 140px;
    }

    .mi-slider nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

demo.css

```
/* General Demo Style */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900);

html { height: 100%; }

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.container > header {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px;
}

.main {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.container > header h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333;
    float: left;
}

.container > header h1 span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/* Header Style */
.codrops-top {
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.codrops-top a {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    color: #000;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
    float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

/* Demo Buttons Style */
.codrops-demos {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.codrops-demos a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.codrops-demos a:hover {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
}

.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
    color: #aaa;
    border-color: #aaa;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="container"> 
            <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top clearfix">
                <a href="http://tympanus.net/Development/SliderPagination/"><strong>&laquo; Previous Demo: </strong>Slider Pagination Concept</a>
                <span class="right"><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=13218"><strong>Back to the Codrops Article</strong></a></span>
            </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
            <header class="clearfix">
                <h1>Simple Multi-Item Slider <span>Category slider with CSS animations</span></h1>
            </header>
            <div class="main">
                <div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01"><h4>Boots</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02"><h4>Oxfords</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03"><h4>Loafers</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04"><h4>Sneakers</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"><h4>Belts</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06"><h4>Hats &amp; Caps</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="img07"><h4>Sunglasses</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="img08"><h4>Scarves</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="img09"><h4>Casual</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="img10"><h4>Luxury</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="img11"><h4>Sport</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg" alt="img12"><h4>Carry-Ons</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="img13"><h4>Duffel Bags</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/14.jpg" alt="img14"><h4>Laptop Bags</h4></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/15.jpg" alt="img15"><h4>Briefcases</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#">Shoes</a>
                        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                        <a href="#">Watches</a>
                        <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.catslider.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {

                $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();

            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/csscustom.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://tympanus.net/codrops/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1"></script>
```

Of course I look up but I don't know what to modify. Thanks for help.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries section in css handles the styling when the page is in small width/mobile devices. Located at [Line #328](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemSlider/css/style.css)

```
/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 910px){
    .mi-slider nav {
        max-width: 90%;
    }
    .mi-slider nav a {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 40px 10px 30px 14px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    .mi-slider {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .mi-slider nav {
        top: 220px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 490px){ 
    .mi-slider {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
    }

    .mi-slider ul {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
        bottom: auto;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .mi-slider ul li {
        -webkit-animation: none !important;
        -moz-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
        padding: 10px 3px;
        min-width: 140px;
    }

    .mi-slider nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I must change in this section. I dont see any margin, paddding..

Comment: In that demo link header has a padding of 30px and `margin-top: 30px;` What actually you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to align `.mi-slider ul` by `top` not `bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query

```
@media only screen and (width:1200px){
    .mi-slider ul li a,.mi-slider ul li h4{
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

Something like that. [Look them up here.](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)